# How to append elements in a list after checking for its duplicates in a loop?

Tags: python, list

I have a bunch of columns with credit card numbers along with other non creditcard numbers which I am reading from a .csv file. I want to filter the credit card numbers first using the regular expression and then passing each of those (card numbers) values to a function that performs the Luhn check to see if valid credit card or not. If the function returns true then I append the index value of the credit card to a list. I am using index values later using .iloc to get the entire row.

This is what I have done so far

```
  data = pd.read_csv("fetched_data.csv")
  summ = data['summary']
  values =np.array(summ)
  creditcards = []
  regex_match_index_list =[]
  Validcardsfound = 0
  no_duplicate_list =[]
  for i in range(len(values)):
    temp = re.findall(r'(\b(?:\d[ -]*?){13,16}\b)',str(values[i]))
    if temp:
        for each in temp:
            if doLuhn(str(each)) is True:
                #print ("In the loop")
                creditcards.append(each)

                Validcardsfound = Validcardsfound + 1
                regex_match_index_list.append(i)

            elif doLuhn(str(temp)) is False:
                pass



      #print (str(temp))
    else:
        pass
```

My question is how do I remove the duplicates cards and then append the index values.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have duplicate card numbers in csv file and want to remove it from there?

Comment: I have the feeling there's a more efficient way to do what you're doing, but it's difficult to help without sample data and a desired output

Comment: Yes, but I want to do it through a program.

Comment: @JuanC yes I think so too.

Comment: i don't know how looks your data but there is [DataFrame.drop_duplicates()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

Comment: `if doLuhn(str(each)) is True:`, ..., `elif doLuhn(str(temp)) is False:`? Are you very very sure about this?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes! It has worked until now. I am just unable to remove duplicates.

Comment: Could you show an example of data['summary'] column? Does each row possibly contain multiple credit card numbers?

Comment: @SiddharthC. It only works because your `else` case is trivial. I don't think `doLuhn(str(other))` is what you really mean.

Comment: @kudeh no. There is just 1 number credit card number in each column. and summary field looks like this 
"the work is being done, pay with VISA 0000000156154 EX 1-21 ZIP 21364"

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes. You are correct. I'll remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a set might be a way to do this:

```
data = pd.read_csv("fetched_data.csv")
summ = data['summary']
values =np.array(summ)

creditcards = set()
regex_match_index_list =[]
Validcardsfound = 0
no_duplicate_list =[]

for i in range(len(values)):

    temp = re.findall(r'(\b(?:\d[ -]*?){13,16}\b)',str(values[i]))

    if temp:
        for each in temp:
            if doLuhn(str(each)):
                # Add unique valid credit card numbers to set
                if not each in creditcards:
                    creditcards.add(each)   #add new card to set
                    Validcardsfound = Validcardsfound + 1  #increment number of unique cards found
                    regex_match_index_list.append(i) #append index of new card found

print(creditcards) # credit cards found
print(regex_match_index_list) # index of credit cards in values array
```

Comment: Won't I lose the index order if I use set? I want the index order.

Comment: isn't the index of unique valid cards being appended to `regex_match_index_list`?